# Trying to identify a transformer

Tags: transformer

I'm trying to identify a transformer input has blue and yellow wires and secondary are black and white and red and orange

Comment: There are enough different "standards" for transformer wire color codes that your description is not helpful.  Please **edit your question**: tell us what equipment the transformer is in, and roughly how big it is.  If you can, post a picture.  If you have an idea of what the transformer is (i.e., is it a power transformer, an audio output transformer, an interstage transformer in some old tube equipment, etc.), then say so.

Comment: Take a picture.  Measure the size.  Where did you get it?

Comment: I would say that vast majority of transformers are custom designs, and the few that are not very much tend to be marked in a useful manner.

Comment: You have given us no context, so you are not trying very hard.  You have some good comments and a good answer to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some simple tests that can identify the voltage, current, and power of a transformer, at least for mains connected power transformer.

1. Read resistance of all windings, and determine which ones have taps and which ones are isolated. From that you can draw a schematic.
2. Apply a 50 or 60 Hz 12 VAC source to the winding with highest resistance. Measure the voltages on all other windings. If this is the 120 VAC primary, the other windings will read 1/10 of their nominal voltages.
3. Slowly raise the applied voltage while reading the current. The current should increase proportionally to the voltage, and at some point the current will rise more quickly. This will occur near the rated voltage for that winding, and this will be the magnetizing current.
4. Compare the size of the transformer to others with a known VA (power) rating, to get an approximation of the rating of the transformer being tested.
5. The rated current will be about 5-10 times the magnetizing current. Calculate the power dissipation using P = I^2 * R. The output power will be about 5 to 15 times the power dissipation, corresponding to an efficiency of 80% to 93%, or losses of 20% to 7%.
6. The rated current of output windings can be similarly estimated using the resistance and voltage.
7. Another useful test is internal impedance, which will be different from winding resistance. Connect the primary to a variable voltage source, and short the secondary winding to be tested, while measuring current. Adjust the voltage until the current reads the rated current (I). Remove the output short, and read the voltage (V). The internal impedance will be V/I. The percent impedance, or regulation, will be this voltage divided by the rated voltage. So if you have a 12 V winding with 1.2 V measured, the regulation will be 10%, and if you draw the rated current, the voltage will drop to 10.8 VAC. Transformer windings are usually rated at nominal current, so a 12 V winding will read about 13.2 V open circuit.
8. Small transformers will typically have poor regulation, perhaps as high as 20-33%. But sometimes they are built this way to limit short circuit current, providing "impedance protection", with short circuit current 3-5x nominal. Large power transformers can have regulation of 2% or so, in which case short circuit current can be 50x nominal.